# Native TCP 9418 git server without ssh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git

How do I set up a git server without SSH, on a ubuntu system?

I have searched for tutorials, and every tutorial only describes how you set up a SSH or HTTP git. I want to set up a native git server with git:// protocol on TCP 9418.

How do I accomplish that?

I do not want to use SSH as this would require setting up accounts for users.

My plan is to set up a read/write git repo without authentication, and then use the firewall to control access via source-IP (since all my users that should have git access have a static IP).

Answer (score 1):

This might be a difficult challenge.  [The git server documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) does a pretty clear job of describing the challenges you will face setting this up, including [set up of xinetd](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-do-i-configure-xinetd-service/):

> **The Cons**
>
> The downside of the Git protocol is the lack of
> authentication. It’s generally undesirable for the Git protocol to be
> the only access to your project. Generally, you’ll pair it with SSH or
> HTTPS access for the few developers who have push (write) access and
> have everyone else use git:// for read-only access. It’s also probably
> the most difficult protocol to set up. It must run its own daemon,
> which requires xinetd configuration or the like, which isn’t always a
> walk in the park. It also requires firewall access to port 9418, which
> isn’t a standard port that corporate firewalls always allow. Behind
> big corporate firewalls, this obscure port is commonly blocked.

The documentation also has a section on [how to start git as a daemon using Upstart](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon).  xinetd would point to that daemon.

Good luck!

---